# KTOR Server StatusPages status() not working

Tags: kotlin, server, ktor

I'm creating a website using KTOR v2.0.0 and I'm trying to set up StatusPages for the 404 & 500 error codes.

Locally this works as expected using the embedded server running the application through Intellij.

When I package the application to a WAR file and run it on a remote server the status() part doesn't seem to get triggered at all but the exception does.

```kotlin
    install(StatusPages) {
        println("StatusPages installed")
        exception<Throwable> { call, cause ->
            println("StatusPages exception triggered")
        }

        status(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) { call, status ->
            println("Page not found!")
        }
        status(HttpStatusCode.Found) { call, status ->
            println("Page WAS found!")
        }
    }
```

The exception works fine but neither of the status() calls work remotely, even though they work fine locally.

I'm using Jetty9 to call the WAR files and I'm using NGINX as a proxy from a domain name to the Jetty9 port. Is there something I'm missing in the process/setup for it to not work?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a bug so I've filed an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-4231.

Comment: @Aleksei Tirman - Thanks for that, didn't occur to me it might be a bug, just assumed I was doing something wrong